# Get all css of only a specific html part and its children

Tags: html, css

I want to get all style properties of a specific html part(div, form, table, ...) and its children. I know how to search for style of any page element, using any browser(chrome, firefox, etc..). Should I look one by one for its children to obtain all css? Is there a way to get all css at one time related with an element and its children ?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to use the Computed Style tab in the Chrome or Firefox web inspectors as this will allow you to see not only the explicitly defined styles of the element(s) in question but will also show you inherited styles from the cascade.

Otherwise you basically just need to copy ALL relevant style definitions from the element(s) and all of their parent and ancestor elements.